# How to load icon for specific weather condition? (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm working on a weather app as a personal project. I have the bases of the app done where I make a HTTP get request to the Yahoo Weather API and it returns the data I want.

However I'm stuck on the next step, getting icons to load with the current conditions.

I setup a JSON file in my "models" folder and it looks like this:

```
[

 {
    "code": 32,
    "icon": "img/sunny.png",
    "text": "Sunny"
 },

 {
    "code": 26,
    "icon": "img/cloudy.png",
    "text": "Cloudy"
 }

]
```

And here's my request for that in my main controller (Not sure if I'm doing it right).

```
    $http.get('models/conditions.json') 
        .success(function(data) {
            vm.condition = data;

        }).error(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

In the view I'm using a combination of the ng-if and ng-src directives to try to load the icons. Again, I don't I'm doing it right.

```
<img ng-if="main.place.item.conditons.code === main.conditions.code" ng-src="{{main.conditions.icon}}">
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work? Am I on the right track? Thanks for any answers!

Comment: What happens? Errors? ng attributes dont need curly braces. You can remove them from your ng-src. That might be part of your issue. Looks like you have some typos in there as well. Check the console for errors.

Comment: @ribsies, I believe `ng-src` does still require the `{{}}` as per the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc).  And @DevonAero, there's a lot you could do, [here's a working jsBin](http://jsbin.com/pudegaguxe/1/edit?html,js,output) but I wouldn't necessarily say that this is the best way.

Comment: The console doesn't give me any errors, but the icons won't load.

Comment: does the `<img>` tags show with no img? or no `<img>' tags generated at all?
I assume you are using ng-repeat? maybe check for any sort of spelling mistakes?

Comment: @SWLim the tags show, but it looks like the src isn't being loaded. This is what I get back: <img ng-if="main.place.item.conditons.code === main.condition.code" class="ng-scope">

Comment: tricky.. have you tried displaying {{main.conditions.icon}} somewhere else (within controller scope and what not), see if it shows the path?

Comment: If the img tag is not showing a src attribute, it's because {{main.conditions.icon}} is not returning anything. Do a console.log on your scope in your main controller, so we can see its layout. Without knowing how the scope looks, we can only make an educated guess as to why it isn't showing.

Comment: I did a console.log(vm.condition[0].icon) after getting the JSON back in my "MainCtrl", and it gave me back the correct value. So should I just wrap the request in a function? Also thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

You said the JSON is being retrieved correctly, so the problem lies in the fact that you are trying to use an array as an object with the ng-src tag. You have {{main.conditions.icon}}, assuming conditions is the JSON you retrieved, you must specify an array index, however, you probably don't want to do this because you don't have a way of knowing what index is related to what weather code.

The solution to this can come in a couple different ways. For one, if possible, you can alter the JSON data to simply be an object in the form:

```
{
    "32": {
        "icon": ...,
        "text": ...
    },
    "26": {
        "icon": ...,
        "text": ...
    }
}
```

If you are able to do this, then you can use conditions as an object and do:

```
<img ng-src="{{main.conditions[main.place.item.conditions.code].icon}}">
```

Of course, this is assuming the conditions property in the "main.place.item" object isn't also an array, if so you will have to adjust even further. Also, I am assuming you made a typo as you had conditions spelled wrong in your question with the ng-if attribute.

Comment: Haha, yep I fixed the typo. Thanks again for all the suggestions, I'll get it working eventually.